# what changes occuried with ubuntu 22.04.1 update on 13 Nov 2022? Networking does not work; Video driver apparently replaced

Tags: networking, nvidia, display-resolution

15 minutes ago Ubuntu 22.04.1 processed a "daily" software change on my primary desktop machine, which required a re-boot.

After the reboot I no longer have access to my local area network or the internet, and the screen resolution on my 4k monitor has been reduced to 1024x768, with no options to change it to any other value...

I am entering this question from a HP laptop that also runs ubuntu 22.04.1 and is not apparently experiencing any problems.This laptop is located in a different room then the desktop, so it will not be easy to run back and forth between the two machines...

(1) my network connection has been totally disabled. Only a ping to 127.0.0.1 has any response. Pinging the computer's assigned static address results in "no response", just like any attempts to ping the main internet router. The LAN in my home office area supports two WIN-10 laptops and my Desktop LINUX system. The WIN-10 systems are not having any problems in accessing each other or the Internet. Only the LINUX Desktop is "offline".

(2) My video card is a NVIDIA GT-710. Prior to the update, it was using NVIDIA 470 driver with X11 server. (wayland doesn't work reliably on the desktop.)

My 4k monitor now only supports 1024x768 resolution and most of the task bar is now display off the screen on the right hand side. (This includs the "settings/logoff/power off" icon.)

"Settings" will not allow me to change the resolution or anything to do with the network.

"Nvidia-settings" no longer displays all of the information about the driver and display like it did before the reboot. (including the ability to change the resolution.) This  implies that the UBUNTU update probably switched me back to Nouveau driver instead of leaving the NVidia 470 driver alone. Obvously I cannot "re-install" the driver until the network works again. (The "Additional drivers" display in Software update say that Nvidia 470 is installed, but I don't think it really is.)

Terrance: (the following is from the current system. did not see your suggestion to reboot previous. will do, and will post any differences...)

```
dkms status
nvidia/470.141.03, 5.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
Sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Expree Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version :09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
   confihuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:da104000-da104fff memory:da100000-da103ffff
```

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatable controller
   product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
   vendor: Nvidia Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus-info pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33 MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
   product: efi vga
   physical id: 1
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   capabilities: fb
   configuration: depth=32 resolution=1074,768
```

Can anyone provide some general guidelines of how to get the network back on and/or get the screen resolution back?

Previous system reports:

```
dkms status
nvidia/470.141.03, 5.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 09
       serial: 08:62:66:26:3b:6c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-52-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168f-1_0.0.5 06/18/12 ip=192.168.7.98 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:34 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:da104000-da104fff memory:da100000-da103fff
```

```
sudo lshw -C video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768
```

As a side comment, no software installs have been made via any process other than "APT".

Previous kernel has networking but monitor is still stuck at 1024x768. will try your suggestion on R8168.

---

Terrance: (14 NOV 2022 7am EST)
When I rebooted under the older kernel I noticed that Networking was back, so I tried your suggestion of  `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`.

It did not help, but I did notice that during the "apt install" it said something about "5.15.0-1007-generic" headers were not available, and so the newest kernel was being bypassed.

It seemed very odd that the kernel would jump from ".52." to ".1007." so I went looking in the various log files, and eventually found some entries in one of the logs that stated that the module "NVIDIA" could not be found in a library named nvidia-470.141.03, so I used the "additional drivers" screen to request Nvidia-driver-470-server to be installed.

This installed the 470.141.03 driver and "nvidia-settings" which has resolved my screen resolution issue.

**Please formulate an "answer" so that I can give you credit, because it was your suggestions that lead me down a long path to a fix for the problem.**

I still cannot determine where the 5.15.0-1007-generic kernel came from, or how the nvidia module became "lost", but I did see a lot of SNAP update failures that finally resolved themselves. (Don't ask me how I feel about SNAP.)

I also saw over 40k sets of lines of JSAPI callbacks being rejected around 08:13:41...

```
Nov 11 08:13:41 wb4alm-07 gnome-shell[1889]: The offending signal was style-changed on Gjs_ui_panelMenu_PanelMenuButton 0x564289342620.
Nov 11 08:13:41 wb4alm-07 gnome-shell[1889]: == Stack trace for context 0x564282035180 ==
Nov 11 08:13:41 wb4alm-07 gnome-shell[1889]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback .not invoked
Nov 11 08:13:41 wb4alm-07 gnome-shell[1889]: The offending signal was style-changed on Gjs_ui_panelMenu_PanelMenuButton 0x564289342620.
```

with no other information or dumps to look at, but that will be a different problem to look into...

Comment: What is the output of `dkms status`, `sudo lshw -C network` and `sudo lshw -C video`.  Add these to your question.  You might have had a Kernel update and these two drivers should have possibly been ready for DKMS but might not have been if you installed them from their direct sources like NVIDIA or HP without using the repos.

Comment: Try also booting to the previous kernel to better run those lines above.

Comment: Terrance: I will attempt a reboot to previous and will see what it said then. will post results, differences.

Comment: If the previous Kernel works, I would recommend that you install the `r8168-dkms` driver by running `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`.  That way that driver retains through new Kernel updates.  And if that NVIDIA driver works in the previous, run `sudo dkms install -m nvidia -v 470.141.03 -k 5.15.0-52-generic` if that is the newest Kernel version that got installed.

Comment: That's odd that you got the `5.15.0-1007` kernel installed.  I would suggest maybe to boot back to the older Kernel and remove that 1007 version.  If you run `dpkg -l | grep "linux-"` you should see the headers, image and modules.  Remove all the ones that pertain to the `1007` kernel by `sudo apt remove linux-image-<rest of name> linux-headers-<rest of name> linux-modules-<rest of name>`

Comment: Terrance - 5.15.0-1007 kernel has been removed. I now have just 5.15.0-52 installed and it is running with nvidia 470.141.03 and x11.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the update was, but I also got an issue with my wifi. It used to be a problem before, but after I compiled a proprietary driver it was fixed once and for all. And then it came back after yesterday's update, even though the proprietary driver is still in the /lib/firmware folder.

Having tried many easy fixes, what I eventually did was the whole git clone of all the drivers (took me 3.5 hours to download it) and adding those to the firmware folder. I've also decided to turn off an auto-update of linux firmware.

If you want to follow my steps (not sure if that would help, but it wouldn't make any damage either), here are the commands:

1. Disable secure booting in BIOS (if not done already);
2. sudo apt-get install git
3. git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git (this step took me 3.5 hours, just to manage your expectations)
4. cd ~/linux-firmware (not sure what the path to linux-firmware is in your case, so please amend accordingly)
5. sudo cp -v -u iwlwifi* /lib/firmware
6. sudo update-initramfs -uk all
7. sudo apt-mark hold linux-firmware (this one is to abstain form any automatic driver updates going forward)